# Bigbluebutton : flash is not working in opensuse

Tags: bigbluebutton

I am installed Bigbluebutton on my server and it is working fine for all the user .

I have a problem with Opensuse users

When i am trying to acces BBB ip in Mozila which is running on `opensuse`  the Bibbluebutton window is not opening for the first time .

When again i am refrshing the page I am getting the Bigbluebutton dashboard.

This is happening only with the OPensuse user.

I tested on Ubuntu ,Mac,Windows it is working fine .

Please tell me the problem here .

Answer (score 0):

I have openSuse 12.3 x64 and Bibbluebutton works fine for me. Here is list of my installed  packets:

1. flash-player           http://download.opensuse.org/update/12.3-non-oss/
2. flash-player-gnome     http://download.opensuse.org/update/12.3-non-oss/
3. flash-player-kde4      http://download.opensuse.org/update/12.3-non-oss/
4. libquvi7               http://download.opensuse.org/factory-tested/repo/oss/
5. pullin-flash-player    http://download.opensuse.org/factory-tested/repo/oss/